# How to calculate the relevance of two words or pharse?

Tags: algorithm, relevance

I need a algorithm to calculate and measure the relevance of two words or phrase, e.g. "Apple" and "iPad".

Can anybody give me some hints or related books on such topics?

Thanks.

Comment: I what you want is not relevance but rather _a measure of relatedness_.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) and [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).  These are methods that are frequently used in information retrieval.  The former quantifies the mutual dependence of two variables (each variable can be a phrase).  The latter was traditionally used by search engines to prioritize results that were relevant to a particular query.